# using openCV SVN repository

Tags: opencv

I want to use openCv 2.2 with Windows Seven, but I found on the web that there is a bug with the web-cam stream on Seven.  But this bug is fixed on the SVN repository.

So I would like to know how I can use the sources from the repository and compile a project with it on visual studio 2010. I try it, but I have a compile time error saying "'opencv2/core/core_c.h' : No such file or directory"

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you try it? Did you follow http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide? Also, this is not really a programming question ...

Comment: Yes I followed the tutorial, but with the repository there is only one file in the opencv2 folder or with the 2.2 there are many files and folders...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the following guideline/tutorial?

http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/